# Mocking LambdaAsyncClient invoke AWS SDK2 in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda

I wondering if there is a way to mock the amazon LambdaAsyncClient without implementing a new client just for test purposes.
I have java code in my service that call AWS lambda,
I created a wrapper client which is none blocking and waiting for a callback:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaAsyncClient
...
private LambdaAsyncClient lambdaAsyncClient;
...

CompletableFuture<InvokeResponse> lambdaCompletableFuture = lambdaAsyncClient.invoke(invokeRequest).whenCompleteAsync(callBack);
```

appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you explain how you are wrapping it? Maybe a bit more code might be helpful here... Have you considered using a library like Mockito ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is using AWS SDK2 which has no configuration of API target, in our sanity test how can I test my code without the dependency of real lambda call